# Get char at a defined location in a string in C

Tags: c

I'm looking to read in a number from the keyboard and then I have to manipulate each digit individually (it's an Octal to Decimal converter).
Is there something similar to the charAt() method from Java that can be used to work with s particular digit?

I currently have the below code (incomplete) but when compiling, it returns "error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Please enter an octal number ending with #");
    char nextNum = getchar();
    char number;
    int counterUp = 0; //Records how many digits are entered
    int counterDown = 1; //Records progress during conversion
    int decimalNumber = 0;

    while(nextNum != '#') //reads in the whole number, putting the characters together to form one Octal number.
    {
        number = (number + nextNum);
        counterUp++;
        nextNum = getchar();
    }


    //Begin converson from Octal to Decimal

    while(counterUp >= 0)
    {
        int added = (number[counterUp] * (pow(8, counterDown)));
        decimalNumber = (decimalNumber + added);
        counterDown++;
    }
}
```

I'm not looking to be told how to go from octal to decimal, just how to work with one digit at a time.

Comment: Please post the full compiler error message, and point out the line in your code that the compiler flags as incorrect.

Comment: The incorrect line is  `int added = (number[counterUp] * (pow(8, counterDown)));`

Comment: Since `number` is a single char, accessing it as if it were an array type doesn't make sense...use an array of characters as suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fgets()` instead of a single char:

```
char number[25]; // max of 25 characters in string

fgets(number, 24, stdin); // read a line from 'stdin', with a max of 24 characters
number[24] = '\0'; // append the NUL character, so that we don't run into problems if we decide to print the string
```

Now you can subscript `number` at will, e.g. `number[10] = 'A'`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're used to Java way where you can write something like:

```
String number = "";
number += "3";
number += "4";
```

Strings in C do not work like that.  This code doesn't do what you think it does:

```
char number = 0;   // 'number' is just a one-byte number
number += '3';     // number now equals 51 (ASCII 3)
number += '4';     // number now equals 103 (meaningless)
```

Maybe something like this will work for you:

```
char number[20];
int i = 0;
number[i++] = '3';
number[i++] = '4';
```

Or, you could simply use `scanf` to read a number in from the keyboard.

I recommend that you find a good book about C and read about strings first, then `scanf` second.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to step back and look at your algorithm more closely.

What does `char number` store? What do you expect this loop to do:

```
while(nextNum != '#') //reads in the whole number, putting the characters together to form one Octal number.
{
    number = (number + nextNum);
    counterUp++;
    nextNum = getchar();
}
```

In particular, what does `number = (number + nextNum);` mean?

Comment: nextNum reads in the next digit from the keyboard and (well, I had previously thought at least) appends it to the end of the number string.

Comment: @user1247751 `char number;` is not a string. It is a single character. In addition, C has no built-in string append operator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define number as an array of chars.

e.g.

```
char number[16];
```

Then change your reading loop to append to the array.

```
while(nextNum != '#') 
{
     number[counterUp] = nextNum;
     counterUp++;
     nextNum = getchar();
}
```